# Чи існує однозначний переклад слова "достопримечательность"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Гадав, що це я забув, але виявилося, що існуючі в інтернеті версії перекладу дуже не однозначні:

> визначна річ, визначна пам'ятка, визначна місцевість и т. п., варта
>   уваги річ, варта уваги пам'ятка, варта уваги місцевість, славна річ,
>   славна пам'ятка, славна місцевість

Є ще регіоналізм з Галичини:

> дивогляд

Але щось підказує мені, що є й інші версії. Чи може хтось запропонувати свою версію?

Comment: Коли шчо, _достопримечательность_ то _достнойно примечательности_.

Comment: На «сучасній мові» це, мабуть, буде: _цікавинка_. Типу: _«які у вашому місті є цікавинки?»_ Але, звісно, це не високий стиль, а розмовний.

Comment: Sasha, a чому б не існувати слову "цікавина" у цьому значенні? "Цікавинка" - це якось по-дитячому. Як "новина" походить від "новий", так і "цікавина" може походити від "цікавий"?

Comment: Цим і гарна українська, що до одного убогого російського слова є 20 синонімів словосполучень. У вашого питання немає відповіді, однозначного перекладу немає. Це все `визначна річ, визначна пам'ятка, визначна місцевість и т. п., варта уваги річ, варта уваги пам'ятка, варта уваги місцевість, славна річ, славна пам'ятка, славна місцевість` підходить плюс ще неназвані варіанти.

Comment: @improbable не треба применувати багатство російської мови. Гадаю, що там теж можна знайти багато синонімів словосполучень. Мову треба плекати незалежно від того розвинена вона чи ні.

Comment: Є подібне запитання: [«Як перекласти українською мовою tourist landmark/site/attraction?»](/q/7431).

Answer (score 5):

Як на мене найбільше пасує наподібок з англійського *showplace* - **показне місце**.

Перше значення [звідси](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53407/31869.html):

> **Показний**. 1. Який привертає увагу певними позитивними якостями; помітний, привабливий: *показна людина, показна зовнішність.* 2.
>   Розрахований на ефект, *навмисно підкреслений: показна веселість,
>   показне геройство.*

Comment: Буль ласка, наведіть декілька прикладів або побудуйте декілька речень англійською мовою з використанням showplace на позначення пам'ятки.

Comment: @RomanMikhol Я не думаю, що це широковживане значення для цього слова. Я думаю, що наподібок з нього зазвичай можна використати як переклад для російського слова з питання.